# How do i remove last particular string using regex?

Tags: php, regex, string

Hi i have the string like below,

```
$aa = "Ability: N/S,Session: Session #2: Tues June 14th - Fri June 24th (9-2:00PM),Time: 10:30am,cname: karthi";

$aa = "Ability: N/S,Session: Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM),Time: #1 only: 1:30pm,cname: ravi";

$aa = "Ability: N/S,Session: Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM),Time: #1 only: 1am,cname: mathi";
```

i need to write single regex for removing the particular string from ",cname:" upto last.
i need output like,

```
$aa = "Ability: N/S,Session: Session #2: Tues June 14th - Fri June 24th (9-2:00PM),Time: 10:30am";

    $aa = "Ability: N/S,Session: Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM),Time: #1 only: 1:30pm";

    $aa = "Ability: N/S,Session: Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM),Time: #1 only: 1am";
```

how can i do this in regex?

Comment: So you want to remove everything after last comma?

Comment: Btw, you don't want to remove everything after ",cname:". You want to keep the last semicolon.

Comment: @m0skit0  yes. i need to remove after last comma.

Comment: yes i need semi colon.. i put semicolon for php format. thats it. actually the string is between the quotes.

Comment: If the string will always be in the same format, you don't need regex - you can simply `$new = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, ',cname'));`

Comment: Sorry, stupid comment about the semicolon...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need regex for this. You can use [strpos()](http://php.net/strpos) to find the index of ',cname:' and then [substr()](http://php.net/substr) up to that index.

```
<?php

$aa = "Ability: N/S,Session: Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM),Time: #1 only: 1am,cname: mathi";
$pos = strpos($aa, ',cname:');
$bb = substr($aa, 0, $pos);
echo $bb, "\n";
```

but if you, for whatever reason, insist on using regex for this, you'll want to use [preg_replace()](http://php.net/preg_replace):

```
<?php

$aa = "Ability: N/S,Session: Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM),Time: #1 only: 1am,cname: mathi";
$bb = preg_replace('#,cname:.*$#', '', $aa);
echo $bb, "\n";
```

and if you don't want to modify the string, you may want to use [preg_match()](http://php.net/preg_match):

```
<?php

$aa = "Ability: N/S,Session: Session #1: Tues May 31st - Fri June 10th (1-5:30PM),Time: #1 only: 1am,cname: mathi";
if (preg_match('#^(.+),cname:.*$#', $aa, $match)) {
    echo $match[1], "\n";
}
```

Comment: Longer code = more potential bugs. Regex is shorter and cleaner.

Comment: For people knowing regular expressions they _may_ seem cleaner. For those not too firm with regex, it just looks like mumbo jumbo. You also cannot argument against performance. Often times plain-string-function approaches outrun regex performance-wise. For this particular problem, I'd personally not have chosen regex.

Comment: Still: longer code = more bugs. Not knowing a technique is no excuse for not using it. If they look like mumbo jumbo, then learn so they don't.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
/,cname:.*$/
```

and replace with an empty string.

```
$result = preg_replace('/,cname:.*$/', '', $aa);
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?306t5)

Comment: Unnecessary replace operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
/^(.*),cname:.*;$/
```

Group 1 ($1) generated by this regex will give you the result you want.

Comment: There is no semi-colon in the OP's string.

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one `,cname:...` and just want to remove the last one, use this:

```
$aa= preg_replace('/,cname:.*?$/', '', $aa);
```